# How To Disable A CSS Text Area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the text are below from a program that I am working on.

```
<div etype="TEXTAREA" style="width: 923px; position: absolute; left: 1px; top: 192px; " class="draggable ui-draggable" id="Element_5857257">
    <label>Log</label>
    <textarea variable="Log" class="form-control" style="white-space: nowrap; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: -6px; width: 923px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; height: 364px; " placeholder="Log"></textarea>
</div>
```

I am trying to disable this text area and make it read only. I have no experience with CSS so I am not sure if this is even possible?

Comment: There was no effort put into this was there? First result of a [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=make+textarea+readonly&oq=make+text+area+read&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l3.4341j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)...

Comment: Also, you should definitely get rid of all of that inline styling. Keep it clean :)

Comment: Maybe I should have been more detailed with my question. I am specifically creating a Desktop application that uses Bootstrap themes for the user interface.

The given answers are not working for my solution. Not sure if it's because the html is not being run in a browser but the text are is not being disabled.

Comment: I'll edit my answer for you, and your updated code.

Answer (score 2):

Like so

```
<textarea disabled>
    strings...
</textarea>
```

in your example just add `disabled` property to you textarea tag

Answer (score 2):

HTML solution:

```
<textarea disabled="true"></textarea>
```

JavaScript solution:

```
var textarea = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
textarea = textarea[0];
textarea.SetAttribute("disabled", "true");
```

Here's edited answer to reflect OP's updated code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var textarea = document.querySelector("textarea.form-control");
    textarea.SetAttribute("disabled", "true");
</script>
```

If you wish, you would copy that bit of JS, and place it probably at the end of `<body>`. Or, you might simply just add `disabled` to the textarea HTML tag. If this is still not the solution you're expecting, then you need to rewrite your question.

Answer (score 2):

**MDN Documenation:**
[Textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea)

Two options:

*disabled:*

> This Boolean attribute indicates that the user cannot interact with the control. (If this attribute is not specified, the control inherits its setting from the containing element, for example ; if there is no containing element with the disabled attribute set, then the control is enabled.)

*readonly:*

> This Boolean attribute indicates that the user cannot modify the value of the control. Unlike the disabled attribute, the readonly attribute does not prevent the user from clicking or selecting in the control. The value of a read-only control is still submitted with the form.

Use whichever fits your use case the best.

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable a textarea just with CSS, with CSS you can "paint" it to looks like disabled:

```
#myTxtarea:disabled {background-color: #EEEEEE;}
```

but it's still accessible, just looks "different".